# Error connecting Erlang and mysql odbc

Tags: mysql, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, erlang

I have an Amazon linux instance on which i have installed a server named ejabberd
Inside it I have a code written in erlang as (db.erl).

```
-module(db).
-export([connection/0]).
connection()->
odbc:start(),
ConnectionString = "DSN=qaz;UID=root;PWD=abc", 
{ok, Ref} = odbc:connect(ConnectionString, []),
Ref.
```

But when I this code is about to run I get an error as

```
[error] gen_server myapp terminated with reason: no match of right hand 
value {error,"[unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 
'/usr/lib/libmyodbc5.so' : file not found SQLSTATE IS: 01000 Connection to 
database failed."} in db:connection/0 line 15

10:34:15.111 [error] CRASH REPORT Process myapp with 0 neighbours exited 
with reason: no match of right hand value {error,"[unixODBC][Driver 
Manager]Can't open lib '/usr/lib/libmyodbc5.so' : file not found SQLSTATE 
IS: 01000 Connection to database failed."} in db:connection/0 line 15 in 
gen_server:terminate/7 line 812

10:34:15.111 [error] Supervisor frequency_sup had child myapp started with 
myapp:start() at <0.502.0> exit with reason no match of right hand value 
{error,"[unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/usr/lib/libmyodbc5.so' : 
file not found SQLSTATE IS: 01000 Connection to database failed."} in 
db:connection/0 line 15 in context child_terminated
```

I have edited my /etc/odbc.ini and /root/.odbc.ini with following configurations

```
[ODBC Data Sources]
qaz= ODBC for MySQL



[qaz]
Driver      = /usr/lib64/libmyodbc5.so
Description = ODBC for MySQL
SERVER      = localhost
PORT        = 3306
USER        = root
Password    = abc
Database    = mydb
```

and my odbcinst.ini file looks like this

```
# Example driver definitions

# Driver from the postgresql-odbc package
# Setup from the unixODBC package
[PostgreSQL]
Description = ODBC for PostgreSQL
Driver      = /usr/lib/psqlodbc.so
Setup       = /usr/lib/libodbcpsqlS.so
Driver64    = /usr/lib64/psqlodbc.so
Setup64     = /usr/lib64/libodbcpsqlS.so
FileUsage   = 1


# Driver from the mysql-connector-odbc package
# Setup from the unixODBC package
[MySQL]
Description = ODBC for MySQL
Driver      = /usr/lib/libmyodbc5.so
Setup       = /usr/lib/libodbcmyS.so
Driver64    = /usr/lib64/libmyodbc5.so
Setup64     = /usr/lib64/libodbcmyS.so
FileUsage   = 1

[MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver]
Driver          = /usr/lib/libmyodbc5w.so
UsageCount              = 1

[MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver]
Driver          = /usr/lib/libmyodbc5a.so
UsageCount              = 1
```

And when I run command

```
isql qaz [root [abc]]
```

I get an error as

```
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
```

Can Anyone tell me the issue and guide me with the correct way to set up odbc configurations in linux
I have done it successfully on windows though, but I am not too familiar with linux.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score -1):

It's the ODBC driver (ODBC Connector) that is provided by mySQL. Did you pre-install the driver? Search how to install mysql odbc driver.

However, I would recommend using another mysql driver, like mysql/otp and not ODBC driver. I've had problems using the ODBC driver with mySql.